# How do I position a label and a button on an image so that even if the image is scaled they are at the same place on the image?

Tags: swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have an almost complete app. I want to use auto layout but even though I have searched a lot about this subject I could not find an answer that I could use. I can get it to show correctly on one screen size but not on another... Here is my question

How do I put the necessary constraints so that even if the counter is scaled for the different sized devices,the label and the button are at the same place on the image? (the image is a png image)

I would really be glad if you can answer or direct me to an answer that shows how to do a similar thing.

This is what I want
[image: Demo Image]

And this is what happens if I try doing it with auto layout and on a different screen size.

[image: Demo Image 2]

- This is not the same image that I am using in my app but it will give you an idea.)

Thanks again

Edit:

Thanks for the answers but as pointed out in the comments, 1st answer does not provide a way to scale the image for different screen sizes.

Second answer provides a way but I could not understand the 2nd part of the answer.I need a little bit more detail. I would be glad if there is anyone out there who can help me on this issue.

I am still struggling with this issue. If I follow the 2nd answer Xcode says I need X position,width for the first filler view and Y position,height for the 2nd filler view.I am stuck at this point. I am not sure what value to give to these views.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the properly scaled images in image assets (1x, 2x and 3x). I tried placing the correct sized images in image assets and auto layout works.

Comment: I have 1x 2x and 3x. I used a mac app called Prepo to create them.But I am not very good at auto layout. Can you tell me the constraints that you used?Am I missing something?Thanks

Comment: I have added a sample project as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the image size will change on different screen sizes, you can't set constant constraints. What you need is proportional constraints.

1. Set your `UILabel` and `UIButton` to have the width and height proportional to the `UIImageView` width and height respectively.

To do that: Click on your `UILabel`

[image]

and Ctrl Drag it over the `UIImageView`, selecting *Equal Widths* and *Equal Heights*.
[image]

Let's say your UILabel has a width of 100px and your UIImageView has a width of 500px. Edit the constraints that you have just set, and set the multiplier to be 100:500
[image]

This will make sure that any modifications on the `UIImageView` width, will affect the `UILabel` width accordingly. Do the same for height constraint.

Repeat same steps for `UIButton`.

2. The top/bottom/trailing/leading constraint cannot be set proportional to the `UIImageView` size unfortunately, but you can have *filler views* - transparent views that can mimic the layout constraints.

You will need two *filler views*: one for top constraint:
[image]

(set its height to be proportional to the UIImageView height)

and one for leading constraint

[image]

(set its width to be proportional to the UIImageView width)

I can make a small video for you if this is not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I was able to follow the first part but I could not understand the 2nd part. Are we pinning the views to anywhere? This is the most complicated thing I am doing in the auto layout.But I think I need to learn it. I would really be thankful for a video.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add constraints with respect to the image view. I have created a small project with your image. This should help you get started.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq8sK_MQLIL9gxMl-lBOMHkToudU

Comment: Keep in mind that in this case, the image view will have the same width and height for every device. It won't scale for different size devices

Comment: I played with this but as @Vlad pointed out it does not scale for different screen sizes. Any way to achieve that?